# Facebook Graph API + Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's Graph API, given a username xyz (assuming they've authenticated my site), how do I get a list of all of the facebook pages that the user administers?

Answer (score 15):

The `accounts` property on the `user` object says:

> The Facebook pages owned by the current user. If the manage_pages  permission has been granted, this connection also yields access_tokens that can be used to query the Graph API on behalf of the page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: Ooh this must be new... never noticed that connection before! Although, I'm not sure this is the right answer. You can be an admin on a page without being the "owner".

Comment: It looks like the right answer to me, it returns all pages I'm an admin on, even the ones I did not create myself.

Answer (score 5):

After getting access token you can get all details of list of all of the facebook pages that the user administers.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[FACEBOOKUSERID]?metadata=1&access_token=
```

The output will look like

```
{
   "name": "Facebook Developer Garage Austin - SXSW Edition",
   "metadata": {
      "connections": {
         "feed": "http://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/feed",
         "picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/picture",
         "invited": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited",
         "attending": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/attending",
         "maybe": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/maybe",
         "noreply": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/noreply",
         "declined": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/declined"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I saw your 'metadata' here by chance, and finally found how to find a User object's connections - just can't help wondering why mention of this metadata collection is nowhere to be found on the official fb docs (at least not, if you don't know what to search). ty, even though my problem was only remotely connected.

Answer (score 4):

Use an fql query! That is the best way to get the pages for which the user is admin. You will also be able to restrict the names also. i.e pages with empty names A sample fql query which gives you the page details as well.

```
SELECT page_id,page_url,name,pic_square FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = " + **UserId** + ") and name!=''
```

*UserId -- Id of the admin*

**NOTE**
This method will not work from version 2.1 of graph api as fql was deprecated from that version onwards

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, you need to use FQL, passing in the appropriate access_token:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid=XXXX&access_token=YYYY

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use. It works perfect

```php
$pages = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => 'SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = '.$uid.''));

foreach($pages as $k=>$v) {
    echo 'page id#:'.$v['page_id'].'<br/>';
}
```

This is of course after you have the session created for the fb user! The `$uid` would be the profile id# of the specific facebook user your returning of a list of managed pages for.

Answer (score 0):

@rmorrison - This is not graph API though. With the new "like" addition, you can use this URL: h ttps://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=blah! or h ttps://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/likes?access_token=blah!

Comment: He's not looking for "likes", he's looking for pages the user administrates.

Comment: Do you know how to perform a like action on a page?

Answer (score 0):

Fql is the best way to get the pages of the user for which he is the admin. As the others like likes of user will give all the pages that the user like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of pages from a simple Facebook Graph API Hit.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/accounts?access_token={access-token}
```

It will give a list of pages for user which he/she has created.

Answer (score -1):

access_token is valid for an hour or less. What should someone do in order to get the details even after. I was trying to result get the result from

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=xyz

This worked for an hour or so but how do i get the result after an hour...without going for a login.