# How can I share a link from Facebook pages that I admin using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have pages that I admin in the Facebook and I want to share a link(not post) from that page using Facebook C# SDK. How can I do that? For clarify question, Facebook pages has link button that you can share link with page's picture.

Comment: Furthermore, the link would have to be *inside* a post.

Comment: i'm searching a way to implement that. But i haven't find yet

Comment: Do you have an option to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK as well?  Making posts with that SDK is very simple...  Also - are you wanting to make this post programatically or do you want the normal share dialog to be displayed to the user when they click on a button?

Comment: if i couldn't manage with Facebook C# SDK i will try to use  Facebook JavaScript SDK. Actually i want to make this post programatically and maybe i can add scheduler option

Comment: Check out [DMCS's](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9296199/558021) answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `facebookclient.Post("me/feed",parameters);`
For the parameters see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: facebook account can have one more pages and i'm thinking that first i  need page id as list then i should use facebookclient.Post() with appropriate parameter. But i really couldn't find a way to do that. I'm using Facabook c# sdk.

Comment: Actually my question is smiliar with this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010707/facebook-graph-api-facebook-pages But i try to implement same thing using C# sdk rather than GraphApi

Comment: The C# SDK talks to the Graph API.  So the format you want is the Graph format.

Comment: i haven't started project yet. I think facebook official language is PHP. Which platform do you advise php(php.sdk) or Facebook C# Sdk with JSSdk?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  There's all sorts of wrapper SDKs around the Graph API.  What is your strong suit?  Do you prefer to program with C#, php, javascript, other?  But for your C# question, it has been answered.  If you have other questions.  Please start that question in a new one.  This is not a discussion forum, it's a Q/A site.  One question one answer please.

Answer (score 0):

```
messagePost["message"] = message;
messagePost["caption"] = caption;
messagePost["description"] = descr;
messagePost["link"] = "http://xxx";

FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(FacebookAdminToken); //users have to accept your app

dynamic fbAccounts = fbClient.Get("/" + FacebookAdminId + "/accounts");

                if (pageID != null)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic account in fbAccounts.data)
                    {
                        if (account.id == pageID)
                        {
                            messagePost["access_token"] = account.access_token;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    dynamic publishedResponse = fbClient.Post("/" + pageID + "/links", messagePost);
                    message.Success = true;
                }
```

Hope his helps.
there is two majour problems with my solution:

1) my FacebookAdmintoken was created using the soon to be deprecated offline_status. there currently is no way for the access_token to stay alive otherwise. Facebook claims it does, but it just doesn't work.

2) there is a bug in the facebook API. when you use post('/id/LINKS') you cannot specify the picture (FB chooses a random pic from the site) and using post('/id/FEED') people can see the result, but they cannot SHARE it.

Seriously FB, get your act together!!!!!